# When to pass headers when scraping a website

Tags: web-scraping, rvest, xml2

I am trying to understand when xml2/rvest commands actually query a website and when it is necessary to specify headers in order to avoid default headers being passed.

```
library(httr)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

url <- "http://testing-ground.scraping.pro"

#open session, passing headers
s <- paste0(url, "/textlist") %>% html_session(add_headers(
  "user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0",
  "Accept" = "text/css,*/*;q=0.1",
  "Accept-Language" = "en-US,en;q=0.5",
  "Accept-Encoding" = "gzip, deflate, br"))

#scrape path list, assuming headers need not be passed again
url_list <- s %>% html_nodes(xpath=".//a[contains(text(), 'Text list')]") %>% html_attr("href")
#Concatenate base URL and scraped paths
url_list <- paste0(url, url_list)

#scrape web page, assuming headers need not be passed again
h <- s %>% jump_to(url_list[1]) %>% read_html()
```

My take on the above code is that the website is queried three times: 1) when session opened, 2) when paths scraped, 3) when webpage scraped. Passing headers when opening the session is sufficient and the same headers will be recycled in the following commands which use the same session.

Is this correct? Will any cookies (and other unspecified header information) also be stored in the session and passed on again to the website?

Answer (score 0):

I understand now that the website is queried only twice:

- 1) when session opened: `html_session()`
- 3) when jumping to another
  URL within session: `jump_to()`

Scraping (`read_html()`) or parsing (`html_nodes()`) from a session does not generate queries since the session already contains the page.

This is not a full answer as I still don't know whether unspecified headers (including cookies) are recycled back to the host.